# One Azure Notification Hub for GCM and FCM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

In the Azure notification hub you can add API key for GCM to send a notification to registered devices, this works at. But GCM will be deprecated next year and Google recommends to use Firebase cloud messaging.

Our users definitely won't update their app immediately so we wanted to support both GCM and Firebase.

[image]

I can only find one 'google' option to add one API key, which is for GCM at the moment. Is it possible to add GCM **and** FCM under **one** notification hub instead of making multiple hubs to send notifications?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key you enter here could be a GCM or an FCM key, either will work but you can't enter both. That's not even necessary since FCM is backwards compatible with GCM, so any device registrations that already exist will continue to work. Note though that after April 1st 2019 you will need to have released an update to your app that uses the FCM API's, since the GCM API's will be retired by that date.